# Start Form's timer from Main Method in program.cs

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I start my app in the system tray like this :

```
static void Main(){

//mutex (Prevents app from running twice
if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

   
    RadForm2 mainForm = new RadForm2();
  

    // Handle the FormClosing event to minimize to tray instead of closing
    mainForm.FormClosing += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        mainForm.Hide();
    };

    // Create a NotifyIcon to display in the system tray
    NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    notifyIcon.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
    notifyIcon.Text = "My App";
    notifyIcon.Visible = true;

    // Handle the DoubleClick event of the NotifyIcon to show the main form
    notifyIcon.DoubleClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        mainForm.Show();
        mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    };

    // Add a context menu to the NotifyIcon for additional options
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Open", (sender, e) =>
    {
        mainForm.Show();
        mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    });
    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", (sender, e) =>
    {
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        mainForm.Dispose();
        Application.Exit();
        //Environment.Exit(0); // if dispose is not used app wont exit
    });
    notifyIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

    // Run the application
    Application.Run();
    
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already running", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

there is a `fileSystemWatcher` control on Mainform that monitors a specific folder and when a change in that folder occurs it starts a timer to send an email.

this is the main issue here :

1. my app starts in the tray without a problem
2. the `fileSystemWatcher` triggers when a change is occurred
3. from this step forward the `timer` wont work.

note: if I double-click on the notify icon and show the main form, everything works as expected but without the main form showing up, `the timer won't work.`

any solution ?

Comment: "there is a fileSystemWatcher control" where?

Comment: I suggest you do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76713334/7444103) (i.e., use a custom ApplicationContext. Also read the notes about the ContextMenu). A Timer component works for sure (assuming this is the Timer you're using). If the issue persists, then there's something in the code you haven't shown that incapacitates it

Answer (score 0):

Going by your description as well as your code I tried to reproduce the issue you're seeing without success. The only unknown seems to be "whatever is happening in the timer handler in `RadForm2`" but in this minimal example (where all it does is update the clock in the title bar) the timer is conspicuously running.

```
internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            var path = Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
            );
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            // Open the folder so we can mess with the files.
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = path, UseShellExecute = true});

            using (var mainForm = new RadForm2())
            using(var fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path))
            {
                mainForm.Disposed += (sender, e) => mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                mainForm.MyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
                {
                    Interval = 100,
                    Enabled = true,
                };
                mainForm.MyTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    // In System Windows Forms.Timer, the Tick is already
                    // marshaled onto the UI thread and won't allow reentrancy.
                    // Other timers are less forgiving than that. To make sure
                    // that it's running, have it update a clock in the title bar.
                    if (mainForm.Visible) mainForm.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                };
                fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                fileWatcher.Created += (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(FileSystemWatcher.Created)}: {e.Name}");
                fileWatcher.Changed += (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(FileSystemWatcher.Changed)}: {e.Name}");
                fileWatcher.Renamed += (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(FileSystemWatcher.Renamed)}: {e.Name}");
                fileWatcher.Deleted += (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(FileSystemWatcher.Deleted)}: {e.Name}");
                mainForm.FormClosing += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        mainForm.Hide();
                    }
                };
                NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
                notifyIcon.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
                notifyIcon.Text = "My App";
                notifyIcon.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon.DoubleClick += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    mainForm.Show();
                    mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                };
                ContextMenuStrip contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
                contextMenu.Items.Add("Open", null, (sender, e) =>
                {
                    mainForm.Show();
                    mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                });
                contextMenu.Items.Add("Exit", null, (sender, e) =>
                {
                    notifyIcon.Visible = false;
                    Application.Exit();
                });
                notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu;
                Application.Run();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already running", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{3B50E02B-383F-4604-AF3E-6B79DD5B0926}");
}
```

---

There are three recommended changes in the code, but they shouldn't really have any bearing on the actual problem you're seeing.

- Moved the mutex release to listen for `mainForm.Disposed` and tested it.
- Changed the `formClosing` so that it keeps the `hWnd` when the user is closing, but allows everything else (like disposing the window when the app is attempting to close).
- Wrapped the `IDisposable` instances in `using` blocks.